# Sci-Fi book revolving about a male character who traveled between dimensions and recorded his travels in logs he sent to his friends

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi, parallel-universe

I've been searching for this series for a while, the story revolved about a group of guardians of sort that travelled between parallel dimensions, through specifically hidden gateways in each dimension, that only said guardians know how to use. None of the people of the parallel dimensions knows about other dimensions, only said, guardians. As I recall, initially the main character often travels with his uncle. I am unsure about the date of publishing of the book, however, I read it in 2014-15.

There should be more than 5 books in this series.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? Perhaps the most important being - when did you read those and when would they have been published?

Comment: Vaguely like Susan Cooper's the *Dark is Rising*, but the guardians spend the entire series in *this* universe.

Answer (score 3):

Is it the Pendragon series you're thinking of?

It features a boy who travels from dimension to dimension to stop the bad guy from destroying various realities. He writes journals back to his friends at home. He travels with his uncle in the beginning.

[Pendragon: Journal of an Adventure through Time and Space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendragon:_Journal_of_an_Adventure_through_Time_and_Space)